# jQuery POST data using FormData with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to post data using ajax, jquery, formdata and then process it using php i'm not able to see where is the error to process it in my PHP file.
The final result is an empty array.

**HTML CODE**

```
<form action="ajax.php?action=upload" method="POST" name="submit_upload_album" id="submit_upload_album" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="input1" name="input1" value="input1">
    <input type="hidden" id="input2" name="input2" value="input2">
    <input type="hidden" id="input3" name="input3" value="input3">
    <input type="hidden" id="input4" name="input4" value="false">
    <input type="hidden" id="input5" name="input5">
    <input type="hidden" id="input6" name="input6" value="auto">
    <input id="title" name="title" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="70" required/>
    <textarea id="description" class="form-control" name="description" rows="4" style="resize: vertical;"></textarea>
    <input id="file1" type="file" name="fileupload[]" accept="video/*" required/>
    <input id="file2" type="file" name="fileupload[]" accept="audio/*" required/>
    <input id="file3" type="file" name="fileupload[]" accept="video/*" required/>
</form>
```

**JS code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        // Submit form data via Ajax
        $("#submit_upload_album").on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "ajax.php?action=upload",
                data: new FormData(this),
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    /*$('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled","disabled");*/
                },
                success: function(response){
                    $('#answer').html(response);
                },
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_FILES);
    echo '<br>';
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Result

```
array(0) {}

array(0) {}
```

Comment: I suggest trying like this example (including using a single file input with the "multiple" attribute, instead of several): https://stackoverflow.com/a/56841778/5947043

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the PHP configuration the problem was coming from

> post_max_size and upload_max_filesize

they were limited on 2M so it was blocking all other posted parameters.

Answer (score 0):

$(this) is not accessible in ajax request you should modify your code as follows:

```
$("#submit_upload_album").on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            let formData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "ajax.php?action=upload",
                data: new FormData(formData),
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    /*$('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled","disabled");*/
                },
                success: function(response){
                    $('#answer').html(response);
                },
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false
            });
        });
```

Hopefully this is helpful for you

Comment: Not sure `serialize` is actually needed here

Comment: unfortunately not working giving me an error

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.`
and this solution without serialize give the same error
`let formData = $(this);`

Comment: also tried this 
`new FormData(document.getElementById("submit_upload_album"))`
and it return an empty array as first return